# Is there any uniqueness for each database in mysql other than database name

Tags: mysql

i have tried using

```
mysql> select * FROM information_schema.schemata;
+--------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| CATALOG_NAME | SCHEMA_NAME                                  | DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME | DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME | SQL_PATH |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| def          | information_schema                           | utf8                       | utf8_general_ci        | NULL     |
| def          | mysql                                        | latin1                     | latin1_swedish_ci      | NULL     |
| def          | performance_schema                           | utf8                       | utf8_general_ci        | NULL     |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+----------+
```

but this did'nt provide any uniqueness for each database other than name

Comment: Well, they also have different default character set and collation. And depending on the InnoDB configuration - they may even reside in different files on the disk.

Comment: What an odd question - why are you asking?